# sub queries in mongodb to get top N in each

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I need to return a collection of topics which each have a "mostRecentThree" property set on them with the 3 newest posts

I have 2 collections

topic

```
{name:'food', foo:bar}
```

post

```
{ topic:'food', created: someDate }
```

return result should be a collection with the recentThree property set

```
{name:food, recentThree: [postId1, postId2, postId3], foo:bar}
```

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What inefficient ways have you tried so far?

Comment: I update a newRecentThree property on insert of a post into the post collection.  Unfortunately because of legacy support I can't set the actual recentThree property directly in the database (which is slightly different with most popular recent 3) so I remap the results of newRecentThree to recentThree after the query comes back.

Answer (score 0):

I am so late to answer, this will help to others,

Using [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) with pipelines,

- The [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) stage adds a new array field whose elements are the matching documents from the “joined” collection, and [$llokup with agregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) Specifies the pipeline to run on the joined collection. The pipeline determines the resulting documents from the joined collection.
- we are going to join `post` collection
- `$match` `topic` and `name` expressions using `$expr` and `$eq`
- `$sort` by date descending *(-1)* order, means latest will first
- `$limit` to get first 3 records that are already sorted in above pipeline

```
db.topic.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "post",
      as: "recentThree",
      let: { name: "$name" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$topic", "$$name"] }
          }
        },
        { $sort: { created: -1 } },
        { $limit: 3 }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/_QXjhk-Qxg4